# CustomPainter in Flutter repaints on each frame during another animation

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-animation

In my Flutter project, I have a widget where there is a `CustomPaint`, and another widget. That other widget only is animated.

But for some reason, the `paint()` function on the `CustomPainter` is called on each frame, even though it's *not* animated.

Here is a sample code:

```
class TestAnimationPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _TestAnimationPageState createState() => _TestAnimationPageState();
}

class _TestAnimationPageState extends State<TestAnimationPage> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {

  AnimationController _controller;
  Animation<double> _animation;


  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller = AnimationController(vsync: this, duration: Duration(milliseconds: 3000));
    _animation = Tween<double>(
        begin: 0,
        end: 700).animate(
      CurvedAnimation(
        parent: _controller,
        curve: Interval(0, 1, curve: Curves.linear),
      ),
    );
    _controller.repeat();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Stack(
          children: [
            SizedBox(
              width: 1280,
              height: 800,
              child: CustomPaint(
                painter: TestPainter(),
              ),
            ),
            AnimatedBuilder(
              animation: _controller,
              builder: (BuildContext context, Widget child) =>
                Positioned(
                  left: 0,
                  top: _animation.value,
                  child: Container(
                    width: 1200,
                    height: 700,
                    color: Colors.redAccent,
                  ),
                ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class TestPainter extends CustomPainter {

  TestPainter() {
    print("this log appears only once");
  }

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    print("this log appears on each frame");
    canvas.drawCircle(Offset.zero, 500, Paint()..color = Colors.amber);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(covariant CustomPainter oldDelegate) => false;
}
```

And here is what I see in the console:

```
I/flutter (11311): this log appears only once
I/flutter (11311): this log appears on each frame
I/flutter (11311): this log appears on each frame
I/flutter (11311): this log appears on each frame
I/flutter (11311): this log appears on each frame
I/flutter (11311): this log appears on each frame
I/flutter (11311): this log appears on each frame
I/flutter (11311): this log appears on each frame
I/flutter (11311): this log appears on each frame
(and so on...)
```

Because of those multiple `paint()` calls, the performance of my animation is getting pretty bad.

So why is it that the `paint()` function is called on each frame, and how can I prevent that?

Thanks.

Comment: check `RepaintBoundary` - but honestly the better approach is to optimize the drawing logic in your painter (if possible)

Comment: Oh! Hey! You again :) I'm going to check that out now, thanks. That said, any idea why `paint()` is called on every frame? Is this a normal behavior, especially if we consider that the constructor of the `CustomPainter` is only called once?

Comment: OK so I got my answer here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Nuni5VQXARo

Comment: and why your `paint` takes that long? tried to speed it up?

Comment: in that simple example, it doesn't take long, but I've got more complex drawings in my real project, and also multiple `CustomPaint`, that's why.

Answer (score 4):

OK so the solution is very simple (thanks again @pskink): just wrap the `CustomPaint` in a `RepaintBoundary` widget, to prevent the `paint()` function of the `CustomPainter` to be called on every frame.

So instead of this:

```
SizedBox(
  width: 1280,
  height: 800,
  child: CustomPaint(
    painter: TestPainter(),
  ),
),
```

do this:

```
RepaintBoundary(
  child: CustomPaint(
    size: Size(1280, 800)
    painter: TestPainter(),
  ),
),
```

Also, quite surprisingly, a good use of the `isComplex` attribute of `CustomPaint` widget might help a lot in some cases.